# java operators and operands

Tags: java, operators, operands

consider

```
    int a =10;
    c = a/a;          //c becomes  1.
    c= a* + a/a ;     //c becomes  1.     
    c= 5+ a* + a/a ;  //c becomes  15.
    c = ++a + a++ - --a - a-- + a * + a/a ;     //c becomes  10.
```

Can someone please tell me how the above works ? Especially the a* part. The first one is only for reference.

Comment: `c= a* + a/a ;     //c becomes  1.` This is wrong, c becomes 10 here.

Comment: That's the unary plus operator.

Comment: `a* + a` is just a confusing way of writing `a * +a / a`, which is a confusing way of writing `a * a / a`

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
c= a* + a/a ;
```

The `+` is the [unary plus operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).  So it is equivalent to

```
c = a * a/a;
```

The variable `a` is 10, so `10 * 10/10` is `10`, not `1`.  Then...

```
c= 5+ a* + a/a;
```

is equivalent to `c = 5 + a * a/a`, so `c` is now `15`.  Then

```
c = ++a + a++ - --a - a-- + a * + a/a ;
```

Pre-increment changes `a` to `11`.  Post increment `a++` increments to `12` but yields the old value `11`, yielding `22` so far.  Then Pre decrement decrements to `11` and the subtraction yields `11`.  Next, post decrement decrements to `10` but yields the old value `11`, and the subtraction yields `0`.  We already know what `a * + a/a` is, `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the third line.

```
c = a * + a / a;
```

There is no postfix `*` operator (`EXPR*`), but there is an infix `*` operator (`EXPR * EXPR`): The multiplication operator. The `*` must therefore be a multiplication operator.

There is a prefix `+` operator (`+EXPR`): The unary plus operator. The `+`  must therefore be a unary plus operator.

The above is equivalent to

```
c = (a * (+a)) / a;
    (10 * (+a)) / a
    (10 * (+10)) / a
    (10 * 10) / a
    100 / a
    100 / 10
    10
```

---

It's exactly the same situation for the `EXPR * + EXPR` in the next line.

```
c = 5 + a * + a / a
```

is equivalent to

```
c = 5 + ((a * (+a)) / a)
    5 + ((10 * (+a)) / a)
    5 + ((10 * (+10)) / a)
    5 + ((10 * 10) / a)
    5 + (100 / a)
    5 + (100 / 10)
    5 + 10
    15
```

---

It's exactly the same situation for the `EXPR * + EXPR` in the last line.

```
c = ++a + a++ - --a - a-- + a * + a/a;
```

is equivalent to

```
c = ((((++a) + (a++)) - (--a)) - (a--)) + ((a * (+a)) / a);
```

The last line both uses and modifies `a` in the same expression. In most languages, the behaviour of such code is undefined because the operand evaluation order is undefined. Even then, understanding when a reference is a placed on the stack as oppose to a copy is crucial, and that makes for poor code.

In Java, [the order is defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7), but it is not actually the case in my testing. Let's look at `((++a) + (a++)) - (--a)` with an initial value of `10` for `a`.

Using left-to-right evaluation:

```
((++a) + (a++)) - (--a)    [a=10]
(11 + (a++)) - (--a)       [a=11]
(11 + 11) - (--a)          [a=12]
22 - (--a)                 [a=12]
22 - 11                    [a=11]
11
```

Using `java`, you get 13. As such, I won't actually show how your last line is evaluated. That would require inspect the generated byte code, which goes to show it's awful code if it's even valid.